# How to identify if a variable should be considered categorical or not while building and training machine learning model?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I have a dataset in which there are 10,000 rows in total and 11 features (customerId, firstVisitDate, secondVisitDate, articleId, section, author, headline, topicKeywords, totalVisits, wordCount, and videoCount).

I am building a machine learning model with the features above predicting the likelihood of a first-time visitor returning to the article. In other words, the likelihood of a first-time visitor of an article converting into a second-time visitor of the same article.

In this problem, I would need to take articleId as a feature to train the model with other important features BUT articleId is a string variable that has 1206 unique values.

Question: Would it be reasonable to consider articleId with 1206 unique values as a categorical variable and then do dummy encoding of it? How to tackle this problem. Any feedback how this can be done in a better way.

Link to the dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EkLxsZgXhLhS6_8eoc-rhDOzAzltyeri/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, articleId is a categorical variable. You could one-hot encode it, but also know that [hashing](https://medium.com/value-stream-design/introducing-one-of-the-best-hacks-in-machine-learning-the-hashing-trick-bf6a9c8af18f) is a viable way to deal with high-cardinality categorical variables.